# What happens to a minor who gets into a traffic accident during driver's training?

Tags: traffic

Hypothetically: What happens to a minor who gets into a traffic accident during driver's training?

Clearly her fault.  Driving the instructor's car with him sitting right by her.  Ideally he would stop her with his set of brakes but that doesn't happen.  Everything gets written up by the police and she has a ticket.  In Michigan if that matters.

Can she get points on her driver's license before having a driver's license?

Comment: Drivers can learn to drive without any sort of license?  Wow.  In the UK and NZ, you need to get a "provisional license" or "learners permit" before you can drive under supervision - and those learners permits or provisional licenses can accumulate points just like anyone else.

Comment: @Moo In the US, or at least in Michigan, you have to take a class before getting a permit.  Part of that class is on the road training.  So here we're talking about before she even got a permit.

Answer (score 2):

Florida has a provision in the law which has been used in the instance of a minor without a driver license. The "computer" creates a license number and assesses/applies penalties to that number. When the minor attempts to get a license, it is denied if the penalties have not been paid. It matters not if there is a crash involved. It's common to see this sort of action for minors who fall under the bicycle helmet law and are charged for the offense, but don't pay it. As a bit of karma, one local police chief discovered that his son hid the penalty from him until it was time to get a beginner's permit.

Answer (score 0):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Learner drivers are required to have a Learner Driver’s Permit which has 4 points before suspension. Learner drivers are required to display ‘L’ plates on the front and rear of the vehicle (rear only for motorcycles).

The learner owes other road users the same duty of care as any other driver.